# How to get oracle.sql.Array as oracle.jbo.domain.Array?

Tags: oracle-adf

I am implementing a PL/SQL backed entity object, according to the instructions in Chapter 4 of Oracle's documentation "Developing Fusion Web Applications with Oracle Application Development Framework".

However, unlike in the documentation example, my entity object contains a column that of a custom Oracle database collection type.  I.e.,

```
create or replace type verp_vps_location_quantity_t as object ( location_type VARCHAR(15), location_key VARCHAR2(3), quantity NUMBER(5,0) );

create or replace type verp_vps_location_quantity_tab as table of verp_vps_location_quantity_t;
```

The Entity Object wizard created a Domain object for VERP_VPS_LOCATION_QUANTITY_T, but not for VERP_VPS_LOCATION_QUANTITY_TAB.  I'm not sure if that matters.

The entity works fine in the Application Module tester in JDeveloper.  But it fails in my overridden EntityImpl class that calls the PL/SQL handler for "doSelect()".  The problem varies depending on how I try to get the VERP_VPS_LOCATION_QUANTITY_TAB type value from the `CallableStatement`.

(A) If I try this:

```
Object array = cs.getArray(parameterPosition);
```

... I get an instance of `oracle.sql.Array`, whereas the ADF framework expects and needs the entity row attribute value to be an instance of `oracle.jbo.domain.Array`.

(B) If I try this:

```
Map<String, Class<? extends Object>> typeMap = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Object>>();                                                    
typeMap.put(pmd.sqlObjectTypeName, oracle.jbo.domain.Array.getORADataFactory().getClass());
Object array = cs.getObject(parameterPosition, typeMap);
```

... I get an `IllegalAccessException`.

So, basically, I am trying to call an Oracle PL/SQL package and retrieve an `OUT` parameter as an instance of `oracle.jbo.domain.Array`.  How do I do it?

Comment: Actually `cs.getArray` should return `java.sql.Array` and if I remember right, it should cast to `oracle.jbo.domain.Array` as is. Even if not, you just have to construct `List` and this will do to construct new  `oracle.jbo.domain.Array`. Sorry, don't have enough time now to check it and write proper answer.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I did wind up constructing a new `oracle.jbo.domain.Array` from a `List`, but it bothers me that I had to do that.  `orace.jbo.domain.Array` implements the `ORAData` interface, so `getObject(parameterPosition, typeMap)` should have worked.  (BTW, `oracle.jbo.domain.Array` does not implement `java.sql.Array`, so it doesn't cast)